# Spit out a list of the last 10 days in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I feel I should qualify all of my questions by saying I am brand new to Rails 3, so forgive me my newbiness. I've been reading the ActionView Date Helpers, but cannot figure out how to complete this simple function. In Rails 3, I want to spit out an html list with the last 10 days. So, for instance, it would look like this today:

```
<li>Tuesday, February 8</li>
<li>Monday, February 7</li>
<li>Sunday, February 6</li>
<li>Saturday, February 5</li>
<li>Friday, February 4</li>
<li>Thursday, February 3</li>
<li>Wednesday, February 2</li>
<li>Tuesday, February 1</li> 
<li>Monday, January 31</li>
<li>Sunday, January 30</li>
```

It seems like it would be simple, but I cannot figure it out. Anyone care to give it a shot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%- Date.today.downto(Date.today - 9.days) do |date| %>
  <li><%= date %></li>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I spit out the day of the week and the name of the month rather than 2011-02-08?

Comment: Just output like this: <%= date.strftime("%A, %B %e") %>

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try looking into [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) to allow you to format information about dates. A website with some ruby strftime formatting can be fount at http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<% 10.downto(1).each do |day| %>
 <li><%= day.days.ago.strftime("%A, %B %d") %></li>   
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<%= (0..10).map { |i| "<li>#{i.days.ago.strftime('%A, %B %d')}</li>" }.join %>
```